# Perl to read each line

Tags: perl

I'm beginner for Perl script.  Below script is to check if file modified time is greater than 600 seconds.  I read filename from `filelist.txt`.

When I tried to print file modified time, it shows modified time as blank.

Could you help me where I'm wrong?

#### `filelist.txt`

```
a.sh
file.txt
```

#### Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $filename = '/root/filelist.txt';
open(INFO, $filename) or die("Could not open  file.");

foreach $eachfile (<INFO>)  {

    my $file="/root/$eachfile";
    my $file_timestamp = (stat $file)[9];
    my $timestamp = localtime($epoch_timestamp);
    my $startTime = time();
    my $fm = $startTime - $file_timestamp;
    print "The file modified time is = $file_timestamp\n";

    if ($rm > 600) {
        print "$file modified time is greater than 600 seconds";
    }
    else {
        print "$file modified time is less than 600 seconds\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include `use strict;` or `use warnings;` which is your downfall.

You set `$fm`; you test `$rm`.  These are not the same variable.  Using strictures and warnings would have pointed out the error of your ways. Expert use them routinely to make sure they aren't making silly mistakes. Beginners should use them too to make sure *they* aren't making silly mistakes either.

---

This revised script:

- Uses `use strict;` and `use warnings;`
- Makes sure each variable is defined with `my`
- Doesn't contain `$epoch_timestamp` or `$timestamp`
- Uses lexical file handles (`$info`) and the three argument form of `open`
- Closes the file
- Includes newlines at the ends of messages
- Chomps the file name read from the file
- Prints the file name so it can be seen that the `chomp` is doing its stuff
- Locates the files in the current directory instead of `/root`
- Avoids parentheses around the argument to `die`
- Includes the file name in the argument to `die`
- Could be optimized by moving `my $startTime = time;` outside the loop
- Uses $fm in the test
- Could be improved if the greater than/less than comments included the equals case correctly

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = './filelist.txt';
open my $info, '<', $filename or die "Could not open file $filename";

foreach my $eachfile (<$info>)
{
    chomp $eachfile;
    my $file="./$eachfile";
    print "[$file]\n";
    my $file_timestamp = (stat $file)[9];
    my $startTime = time();
    my $fm = $startTime - $file_timestamp;
    print "The file modified time is = $file_timestamp\n";

    if ($fm > 600) {
        print "$file modified time is greater than 600 seconds\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$file modified time is less than 600 seconds\n";
    }
}
close $info;
```

---

Tangentially: if you're working in `/root`, the chances are you are running as user `root`.  I trust you have good backups. Experimenting in programming as `root` is a dangerous game. A simple mistake can wipe out the entire computer, doing far more damage than if you were running as a mere mortal user (rather than the god-like super user).

Strong recommendation: **Don't learn to program as root!**

If you ignore this advice, make sure you have good backups, and know how to recover from them.

(FWIW: I run my Mac as a non-root user; I even run system upgrades as a non-root user. I do occasionally use root privileges via `sudo` or equivalents, but I never login as `root`. I have no need to do so. And I minimize the amount of time I spend as `root` to minimize the chance of doing damage. I've been working on Unix systems for 30 years; I haven't had a root-privileged accident in over 25 years, because I seldom work as root.)

Answer (score 1):

What others have run into before, is that reading the filename from the file `INFO` you end up with a newline character at the end of the string and then trying to open `/root/file1<cr>` doesn't work because that file doesn't exist.

Try calling:

```
chomp $eachfile
```

before constructing `$file`